# Sending cookies automatically in cross-origin XHR requests

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I've developed a plugin for a web site, for the sake of this post let's call it [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com)
The plugin has authorization page on my website, let's call it [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), which returns cookie upon authorization, which I obviously want to use in subsequent requests to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com).

The plugin uses dynamic rules to change Access-Control-Allow-Origin on request to [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com) to "*", so cross-origin requests can be sent from the page to [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com). However cookies of [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) are not passed automatically with the request when I send requests from plugin's injected code using XMLHttpRequest. As I understand this is intended browser behavior to prevent "stealing" cookies via cross origin requests, and cookies are only passed if the request is originated from the browser itself.

Question is, is there a way around this? Obviously I'm not trying to steal your cookies :) I just need the cookies of [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) to be sent automatically in XHR requests I send from the webpage on [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com) domain.

I've seen a similar question, but it required to modify response headers of the origin site, which I obviously have no access to, so in my case that solution won't work. I have access to backend of  [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), front end of [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), frontend of [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com) (via script injection via plugin) and NO ACCESS to backend of [www.somesite.com](http://www.somesite.com).

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a samesite cookie issue? What samesite value does the cookie have?

Comment: @ToreNestenius The cookie is returned as samesite and secure from the authorization request. It feels like I'm missing something in the request.

Comment: I would use a tool like https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler to examine the requests.